# initialize ServletContext using a method on a Resin server

Tags: java, servlets, resin

Is there a way to initialize the ServletContext for a webapp on a Resin server using a method? I need something like  that runs once, when the server starts up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `<load-on-startup/>` in the `<servlet>` tag.

Comment: That's for `Servlet` initialization, not `ServletContext` initialization.

Comment: But the Servlet object has access to the ServletContext at that point, right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `ServletContextListener`.

http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-servlet/how-to-work-with-servletcontextlistener.html

> This J2EE tip demonstrates use of
>   ServletContextListener. This event
>   class handles notifications about
>   changes to the servlet context of the
>   Web application that they are part of.
>   This can be explained as if someone is
>   present on the server and dynamically
>   informing us about the events that are
>   occuring on the server. There acquire
>   need of Listners. Therefore,
>   ServletContextListner is helpful in
>   informing about context Initilazation
>   and destruction.